# What is the difference between "forcibly" and "forcefully"?

Tags: word-choice

The scene I am writing is about a woman seducing a soldier on battlefront. She provokes him by lifting her face and keeping it at a few inches from his. He replies by holding her by the back of her head and kissing her.

*He held his hands on the back of her head and pressed her lips on his. She posed a weak resistance, further provoking him as he kissed her ----------*

What is a better choice for word here? *forcibly* or *forcefully*?

Comment: You are likely to get better, more in-depth answers if you cite dictionary entries for both of these words to show that you already know their basic definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Forcefully  sounds more appropriate in your context:

***[Forceful vs forcible](http://grammarist.com/usage/forceful-vs-forcible/):***

> - ***In general, forceful describes a person or thing that is powerful, forcible describes the use of power.***
> - ***Forceful*** means powerful, assertive, effective. ***Forceful is an adjective which may describe a person or argument, among other things.*** A derivative is the noun, forcefulness. Forceful comes into use in the 1570s.
> - ***Forcible*** means accomplished through force. ***Forcible is an adjective which means vigorous, strong, effective.*** Derived forms are forcibleness, forcibility, forcibly. Forcible came into use in the early 1500s from the Old French forcier, meaning conquer by violence.

Usage examples:

> - It took courage and determination ***to implement such a forceful policy*** given the protests from human rights groups and our regional neighbours. (The West Australian)
> - Taipei defends ***forcible demolition*** of man’s home (The Taipei Times)

(The Grammarist)

[Usage note](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/Forceful-And-Forcible.htm):

> - ***Forceful, forcible, and forced*** have distinct, if related, meanings. ***Forceful*** is used to describe something that suggests strength or force: a forceful argument. Forceful measures may or may not involve the use of actual physical force. ***Forcible*** is most often used concerning actions accomplished by the application of physical force: *There had clearly been a forcible entry into the storeroom. The suspect had to be forcibly restrained.*
> - ***"Forced*** is used to describe a condition brought about by control of an outside influence: Products made by forced labor are generally shunned in the international marketplace. It became necessary for the pilot to make a forced landing. Her displeasure was evident in her forced smile."

(Webster's New Essential Writer's Companion. Houghton Mifflin, 2007)

Comment: Many thanks! I have realized that indeed I should use "forcefully" here as her resistance was only for seduction sake, not to actively stop him (in which case "forcibly" would have been the adequate choice).

Comment: @YoustayIgo - please remember to add your research in your future questions.

Comment: Such a good answer should be enough to save the question.